# asp.net core 3.1 how to implement ConfigurationProperty with AppSettings from appsettings.json

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, appsettings

I have the following class from an **old** .NET MVC project:

```
public class MatchConfiguration : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("Threshold", IsRequired = false, IsKey = false)]
    public string Threshold
    {
        get
        {
            return this["Threshold"] as string;
        }
        set
        {
            this["Threshold"] = value;
        }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("CertaintyThreshold", IsRequired = false, IsKey = false)]
    public string CertaintyThreshold
    {
        get
        {
            return this["CertaintyThreshold"] as string;
        }
        set
        {
            this["CertaintyThreshold"] = value;
        }
    }

    //subsections
    [ConfigurationProperty("nonSignificativeWords")]
    public PatientMatchWordCollection NonSignificativeWords
    {
        get
        {
            return this["nonSignificativeWords"] as PatientMatchWordCollection;
        }
    }
}
```

In the web.config I used to have a section with:

```
<section name="match" type="Test.Service.MatchConfiguration"></section>
```

And also in the web.config:

```
<match Threshold="92.2" CertaintyThreshold="28">
<nonSignificativeWords>
      <words word="LA" />
      <words word="DY" />
</nonSignificativeWords>
</match>
```

Now on AspNET Core 3.1 there is only `appsettings.json` file. I already know how to create an `AppSettings` class and bind an `AppSetting` section.

```
// configure strongly typed settings objects
var appSettingsSection = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
services.Configure<AppSettings>(appSettingsSection);
```

And my `appsettings.json`

```
"AppSettings": {
    "Threshold": 92.2,
    "CertaintyThreshold": 28,
    "nonSignificativeWords": [
     {
     "word":"LA"
     },
     {
     "word":"DY"
     }]
  }
```

This is `AppSettings` class:

```
     public class AppSettings
        {
            public double Threshold { get; set; }
            public double CertaintyThreshold { get; set; }
            public List<Word> nonSignificativeWords { get; set; }
        }

public class Word
        {
            public string Word{ get; set; }
        }
```

How can I still using `ConfigurationProperty` as the `MatchConfiguration` class so it takes the values from the `AppSettings`?

> Any advice or recommendation or workaround?

Comment: I do not quite understand what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: Trying to set automaticly to the property the value from appsettings, just as ConfigurationProperty works when using Web.config

Comment: The wording of your sentence is what confuses me. Are you still trying to use `ConfigurationSection` in Core?

Comment: No, im trying to migrate that funcitonality from old MVC project to net core using appsettings but trying to keep ConfigurationProperty attribute on my class. But maybe this wont work for .netcore.

Comment: Yeah, I am not seeing how the two versions would work together. They basically left ConfigurationManager behind.

Comment: Can you show the AppSettings class

Comment: Sure let me update thread

Comment: @Nkosi Updated.

Comment: Could you explain why you want to do this? Maybe there are other solutions to whatever the problem is

Comment: Based off of what you have so far, I think the recommendation would be to just use the `AppSettings` class